# Is a function in an ideal? Verification by hand and Macaulay 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, math-software, groebner-basis, macaulay2

Suppose 
$$f_1=-4x^4y^2z^2+y^6+3z^5,$$ 
$$f_2=-4x^2y^2z^2+y^6+3z^5,$$
$$f_3=4x^4y^2z^2+y^6+3z^5,$$ 
$$f_4=4x^2y^2z^2+y^6+3z^5$$

and

$$I=\langle xz-y^2,x^3-z^2\rangle\subset\mathbb C[x,y,z].$$

**Is $f_i\in I?$**

---

The answer is **Yes** in some cases.

The question can be checked with Macaulay 2: when the remainder is zero with respect to the Gröbner basis like *`(R=QQ[x,y,z]; fi=...; I=ideal(x*z-y^2,x^3-z^2); G=gb(I);f%G`* returning zero, $f_i\not\in I$.

Division with respect to the elements in ideal or with respect to polynomials in the basis does not result into the case with zero remainder as demonstrated in the trials with Lex, RevLex and with polynomials in Gröbner basis and with respect to polynomials in the ideal (in larger resolution [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3eNK.png), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhUVR.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGpMJ.png)) where all trials fail because not finding the zero remainder case.

[image]

Checking whether a polynomial is in an ideal can be done by hand such as manually with division algorithm and with Macaulay2 such as finding the correct factors, decomposition of the polynomial with quotients and GR elements. So

**How can you check that a polynomial is in an ideal by hand and computationally such as Macaulay 2?**

*P.s. Other questions on learning basic computational algebraic geometry in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27678547#27678547).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the lex order. In your computation you misinput $-4x^2y^2z^2+y^6+3z^5$ as $4x^2y^2z^2+y^6+3z^5$. Otherwise using lex order can easily give you remainder $0$.

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{cc}
                    &-4z^2 + 1  \\[-3pt]
x^3-z^2& \enclose{longdiv}{-4x^2y^2z^2+y^6+3z^5} \\[-3pt]
x^2y^2-z^3 &        \underline{-4x^2y^2z^2+4z^5}\phantom{+3z^5} \\[-3pt]
xy^4-z^4 &                    y^6-z^5  \\[-3pt]
xz-y^2 &         \underline{y^6-z^5}\\[-3pt]
y^6-z^5& 0
\end{array}
$$

Apparently then $f=-4z^2(x^2y^2-z^3)+(y^6-z^5)$.

Here is a program in Sage that I adopted from: http://www.math.utah.edu/~carlson/cimat/lecture1.pdf:

```
def div(f,g):
n = len(g)
p, r, a = f, 0,  [0 for x in range(0,n)]
while p != 0:
    i, divisionoccured = 0, False
    while i < n and divisionoccured == False:
        if g[i].lt().divides(p.lt()):
            a[i] = a[i] + p.lt()//g[i].lt()
            p = p - (p.lt()//g[i].lt())*g[i]
            divisionoccured = True
        else:
            i = i + 1
    if divisionoccured == False:
        r = r + p.lt()
        p = p - p.lt()
return a, r
```

Results from running the above algorithm:

```
P.<x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(QQ,order='lex')
I = ideal(x*z-y^2,x^3-z^2)
B = I.groebner_basis(); B
f = -4*x^2*y^2*z^2+y^6+3*z^5
div(f,B)
[x^3 - z^2, x^2*y^2 - z^3, x*y^4 - z^4, x*z - y^2, y^6 - z^5]
([0, -4*z^2, 0, 0, 1], 0)
```

Comment: +1 for observing the typo, do you know how to verify things with Macaulay2? It is very easy to do mistakes by hand.

Comment: @hhh: I think your method is correct. Find a Groebner basis, with any order. Then divide $f$ by the Groebner basis. If the remainder is $0$, $f$ is in the ideal. I used SAGE to verify. I haven't used Macaulay2. But the methods are the same.

Comment: Are you able to factor $f$ with respect to GR pols in Sage? Added corrected Lex example [here (not able to factor even now with respect to the GR pols, can you see why?)](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1665233/5902) And a solution by Macaulay2: yet haven't found yet a command to factor polynomial with respect to certain polynomials.

Comment: Moved the more programming related thing to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534015/how-to-factor-polynomial-with-other-polynomials): basically the question is about how to factor a polynomial with respect to other polynomials as far as I understand it, so on division algorithm.

Comment: @hhh: With lex order, your order of divisors are not correct. See my edit. As for the coefficients, Jesper Freesbug's answer is a good way to go.

Comment: It is interesting that we have found now 3 different factorisation with respect to the same GR polynomials, [Macaulay quotient command](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1665233/5902) found a new expression for the $f:=f_2$. Do you know how can you find all possible expressions for $f_2$ with respect to the GR?

Comment: @hhh: It seems that Macalay was following an arbitrary order to arrange the Groebner basis, and arbitrary order to divide. I assume if you follow different orders, you can always end up with different result. But I don't know if that is useful to find.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that Macaulay2 solution in terms of ideal quotients differs from the solution by hand. Consider $f_2=-4x^2y^2z^2+y^6+3z^5$. M2 in the polynomial ring with Lex order provided

$$f_2^{lex,M2}=(3x^2z^2-xy^2z-y^4)(xz-y^2)+(-3z^3)(x^3-z^2)$$

while by hand in inverse lexicographic order

$$f_2^{invlex}=(-4xy^2z-4y^4)(xz-y^2)-3(y^6-z^5)$$

and by KittyL in Lex order

$$f_2^{lex,Hand}=-4z^2(x^2y^2-z^3)+(y^6-z^5)$$

where $f_2^{lex,M2}$ should be equal to $f_2^{lex,Hand}$ but it is not: so M2 is using some different order in division and quotients. **It is a task to investigate why M2 provides so different result.**

**Macaulay2**

```
R=QQ[x,y,z,MonomialOrder=>Lex]; f=-4*x^2*y^2*z^2+y^6+3*z^5; 
I=ideal(x*z-y^2,x^3-z^2); G=gb(I);f//gens G
gens G
(3*x^2*z^2-x*y^2*z-y^4)*(x*z-y^2)+(-3*z^3)*(x^3-z^2)
f//gens G
matrix(gens G)*matrix(f//gens G)==(3*x^2*z^2-x*y^2*z-y^4)*(x*z-y^2)+(-3*z^3)*(x^3-z^2)
```

[image]

and computational aspect, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534015/how-to-factor-polynomial-with-other-polynomials), about finding the factors/coefficients for the polynomials so that the linear combination equals zero.

**By hand**

On KittyL's observations with corrections such as $f$, division algorithm with respect to inverse Lex on $f$ and dividing with the polynomials in the Gröbner basis of the ideal:

[image]