# Handelman's Theorem on Nonnegative polynomial in Compact Polytope?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polytopes

> **Background:** [Representing polynomials by positive linear functions on compact convex polyhedra by David Handelman](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102689794)

Consider a polynomial $f\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ in a compact polytope, related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868596/polynomial-in-compact-polytope-algebraic-description-for-the-compact-polytope) on trying to formulate the polytope algebraically, where each variable $x_i$ is defined in some compact set such as $x_1\in [0.2,0.5]$.

*Example 1: is $f$ non-negative in $K$? Yes for $f_1$, no for $f_2$.*

> $f_1[x_1,x_2,x_3]=x_3-x_1 x_2$
>
> $f_2[x_1,x_2,x_3]=x_3x_2-x_1$
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> x_{1} & \in & [0.2,0.5]\\
> x_{2} & \in & [0,1]\\
> x_{3} & \in & [1,1]
> \end{eqnarray*}

*Example 2: is $f(x_{1},x_{2})=x_{1}-x_{2}$ positive on the polytope $K$ restricted by the intervals?*

> The answer is no in the example below but how do we use Handelman's theorem on this?
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> 0.1<x_{1}<0.5 & \Leftrightarrow & x_{1}>0.1,-x_{1}>-0.5\\
> 0.2<x_{2}<1 & \Leftrightarrow & x_{2}>0.2,-x_{2}>-1\\
>  & \Rightarrow & \begin{cases}
> \beta_{1}=x_{1}-0.1\\
> \beta_{2}=-x_{1}+0.5\\
> \beta_{3}=x_{2}-0.2\\
> \beta_{4}=-x_{2}+1
> \end{cases}
> \end{eqnarray*}
>
> where $\{\beta_i\}=\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3,\beta_4\}$ and we guess the right *"positive
>   linear combination of products of members of $\{\beta_i\}$"* (but it may not easy to come up with it)
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> f & = & a\beta_{1}+b\beta_{2}+c\beta_{3}+d\beta_{4}\\
>  & = & a(x_{1}-0.1)+b(-x_{1}+0.5)+c(x_{2}-0.2)+d(-x_{2}+1)\\
>  & = & x_{1}(a-b)+x_{2}(c-d)+(-0.1a+0.5b-0.2c+d)\\
>  & \underset{f_{1}}{=} & x_{1}-x_{2}\\
>  & \Rightarrow & a-b=1,c-d=-1,-0.1a+0.5b-0.2c+d=0\\
>  & \Rightarrow & \begin{cases}
> b-a=c-d\\
> 0.9a-0.5b+0.8c+d=0
> \end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
> d=c+a-b\\
> 0.9a-0.5b+0.8c+d=0
> \end{cases}\\
>  & \Rightarrow & 0.9a-0.5b+0.8c=0
> \end{eqnarray*}
>
> where the [positivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1877531/5902) actually means that $a,b,c,d\geq 0$ and all values of $a,b,c,d$ cannot be zero at the same time. Since $a-b=1\Rightarrow a=1,b=0$ (only case satisfying this). $c-d=-1$ so $c=0,d=1$ (similar as earlier). So
>
> $$-0.1a+0.5b-0.2c+d=0 \Leftrightarrow 1+4b+8d=0$$
>
> which cannot be true since $b,d$ are not negative. So no function $f$ exists in the basis so by Handelman's theorem f is not non-negative in the polytope restricted by the inequalities. No positive linear combination of products of members of $\{\beta_i\}$ terms can express $x_1-x_2$ so $f$ is not non-negative.
>
> ---
>
> **How can I computationally check the condition on the positivity?**
>
> I. Macaulay2 [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662152/is-a-function-in-an-ideal-verification-by-hand-and-macaulay-2) with hand-on examples and trying to define the ideal for the intervals error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723098/constants-in-terms-of-ideal-stdio4113-error-cant-promote-number-to-rin). Define quotient ring for the $\{\beta_i\}$ (originating from inequalities)?
>
> ```
> R=RR[x1,x2];
> f=x1-x2;
> intervals=ideal(x1-0.1,-x1+0.5,x2-0.2,-x2+1);     
> f%intervals
> i4 : f%intervals
> o4 = 0
> o4 : R
> ```
>
> and verified with
>
> ```
> R2=RR[x1,x2]/(x1-0.1,-x1+0.5,x2-0.2,-x2+1);
> f2=x1-x2
>
> i11 : f2
> o11 = 0
> o11 : R2
> ```
>
> that is a contradictive result: we showed that $x_1-x_2$ on $K$ can be expressed as a positive linear combination of products of members of $\{\beta_i\}$, did we? We know by the Handelman's theorem that this should not be possible -- $x_1-x_2$ is negative when $x_1=0.1$ and $x_2=1$ so we should not be able to express it in terms of the products.
>
> ---
>
> *Numeric notice in dealing with numeric real values, `I_0+I_2==f` should be true (but false because of the small $\epsilon=-5.55112e-17$)*
>
> ```
> i35: R=RR[x1,x2];f=x1+x2-0.3;I=ideal(x1-0.1,-x1+0.5,x2-0.2,-x2+1); I_0+I_2 - f 
> o34=  -5.55112e-17
> ```
>
> *so with exact arithmetics*
>
> ```
> i1 : R=RR[x1,x2];f=x1+x2-3/10;I=ideal(x1-1/10,-x1+1/2,x2-1/5,-x2+1); I_0+I_2 - f    
> o3 : Ideal of R
> o4 = 0
> o4 : R
> ```
>
> ---
>
> II. [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/122004/polynomial-in-compact-polytope-polynomialreduce-with-positive-poly-terms-and) where PolynomialReduce but cannot find a way to specify that each quotient term positive and remainder zero.

**How does Handelman's Theorem work to check non-negativity of $f$ in some compact polytope?**