# Nichtnegativstellensatz the same as Handelman's Theorem?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, definition, compactness, polytopes

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial#cite_note-5) on *"Handelman's theorem: If $K$ is a compact polytope in Euclidean $d$-space, defined by linear inequalities $g_i ≥ 0$, and if $f$ is a polynomial in $d$ variables that is positive on $K$, then $f$ can be expressed as a linear combination with non-negative coefficients of products of members of ${g_i}$."* where the context is the positive polynomials and Farkas' lemma is the Positivstellensatz but often not called by that name so I am curious which theorems fall under Nichtnegativstellensatzen. I am particularly interested in compact polytopes.

---

Related on this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868615/handelmans-theorem-on-nonnegative-polynomial-in-compact-polytope) on using Handelman's theorem to check nonnegativivity of a polynomial in a compact polynomial but now focus on terminology and jargon.

**Are Handelman's theorem and Nichtnegativstellensatz the same thing?**

> 1. How are Handelman's theorem and Nichtnegativstellensatz related for compact polytopes?
> 2. Which Nichtnegativstellensatz is relevant to determine non-negativity in compact polytopes? What about with Handelman's theorem?
> 3. What are the difference between different Nichtnegativstellensatzen? [The Satz by Stengle](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jbhu2010/PRESENTATIONS/JBHU2010_Lasserre.pdf)
>
> > $$f\geq0 \text{ on } K \Leftrightarrow hf=f^{2s}+p$$ for some integer
> >     $s$and polynomials $h,p\in P(g)$. Moreover bounds for $s$ and degrees
> >     of $h,p$ exist.

Answer (score 1):

The Nichtnegativstellensatz is true for compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ while Handelman's theorem holds for polytopes, so the former is more general than the latter.

For the specific case of polytopes, which can be thought of as a semialgebraic set defined by degree 1 polynomials, it seems to me from [this set of slides](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jbhu2010/PRESENTATIONS/JBHU2010_Lasserre.pdf) and [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial) that Handelman's theorem makes a stronger statement.

[Lasserre's Book](https://books.google.com/books?id=IRZoBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=Stengle%E2%80%99s%20NichtNegativstellensatz&source=bl&ots=W413G1nXf8&sig=ACfU3U1VDvTzZGl61lv--paElTqpxZQbtQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2-tL86MPhAhUIJt8KHcF6AIoQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Stengle%E2%80%99s%20NichtNegativstellensatz&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot answer the question but I am trying to gather potentially relevant material to answer this question, work in progress until trying to target the question.*

I could find the threads and material sometimes relevant for positive polynomials but also focus on nonnegative polynomials

1. [Nonnegativity condition for a polynomial in two variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181483/nonnegativity-conditions-for-a-polynomial-in-two-variables)
2. Lecture [slides](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~njw/Teaching/Math271C/Lecture_22.pdf) on positive polynomials introduce you to non-negative polynomials.
3. [Stengle's Nichtnegativstellensatz](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jbhu2010/PRESENTATIONS/JBHU2010_Lasserre.pdf)