# "Positive linear combination" of products of members of $\{\beta_i\}$?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, convex-analysis, definition

I want to verify that I understand the term *"positive linear combination"* [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102689794) in the first sentence of the abstract correctly. Consider $a+b+1=0$ and $a-b+1=0$ where $a,b$ are variables in some polynomial ring, are the polynomials both positive or does $-b$ in the latter make it negative linear combination? This is important to understand the second example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1868615/5902).

**What does particularly the part *"positive linear combination"* mean exactly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some vectors $\{\beta_i\}_{i = 1}^n$, then a positive linear combination is
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i \, \beta_i,$$
where all $\lambda_i$ are non-negative. It does not mean that the $\beta_i$ satisfy some notion of positivity.

Comment: Can the positive mean also to be zero i.e. not strictly positive but positive? I am uncertain because this [abstract](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102689794) introduces the positivity and the strict positivity: I understand it such that $f$ is strictly positive $>$ if a positive linear combination exist -- where I am uncertain whether all $\lambda_i$ could be zeroes, I think all lambdas cannot be zeroes but uncertain whether a few values could be equal to zero.

Comment: In the situation of the abstract, some $\lambda_i$ has to be positive, since the resulting linear combination is a strictly positive polynomial. In general, I would say that the all-zero linear combination is a positive linear combination (since all $\lambda_i$ are non-negative).